# How to adjust the column size of WooCommerce admin products table

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have added some extra columns in my WooCommerce admin products list but the columns are not adjusted according to values and I have the following problem
[image]

How can I change CSS of the table

```
table.fixed {
   table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: It's just a matter of applying CSS in WordPress backend. What are the IDs (column names) you used when creating the columns?

Comment: For example the GTIN has _gtin as id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wc_product_list_css_overrides');

function wc_product_list_css_overrides() {
    wp_add_inline_style('woocommerce_admin_styles',
            "table.wp-list-table .column-sku{ width: 9%; } table.wp-list-table .column-name{ width: 20%; } table.wp-list-table .column-is_in_stock{ width: 7%; }");
}
```

Please take the corresponding column name and enter the width value desired like the example given.

Add the above code in your active theme functions.php file

Comment: So you suggest putting all columns one by one using their names to be sure that it will not be messy? or only those I want?

Comment: Only those columns you want to adjust

Comment: It seemed correct approach but is not working. Something overides and nothing changes

Comment: { width: 9% !important; }. --- Try adding important

Comment: I tried it as well the !important

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer but this will help anyone that google search

Based on @mujuonly answer

need to add priority like 998

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wc_product_list_css_overrides', 998);

function wc_product_list_css_overrides() {
    wp_add_inline_style('woocommerce_admin_styles',
            "table.wp-list-table .column-sku{ width: 9%; } table.wp-list-table .column-name{ width: 20%; } table.wp-list-table .column-is_in_stock{ width: 7%; }");
}
```